# Spring Data JPA JPQL list in constructor

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my application, a non-standard situation, I have a layer of entity in mysql, layer of dominain in controllers. My domain model contains a few entities, can this be integrated into one JPQL query?

> entity layer:

PersonEntity table

EventEntity table

EventVisitorEntity table

1. PersonEntity many to many EventEntity
2. EventVisitorEntity interim table

> domain layer:

```
class PersonInfo {
Person person;
List<PersonEvent> personEvent
...
}
```

Now I get all Person to take their ids and get the PersonEvent, using this query:

```
@Query("SELECT new domain.PersonEvent(ev.personId,ev.eventId,e.name,ev.state)" +
        " FROM EventVisitorEntity AS ev ,EventEntity AS e WHERE e.id = ev.eventId AND ev.personId IN (?1)")
List<PersonEvent> findEventsForPerson(List<Integer> ids);
```

It is possible to write one query to get persons with an personEvents ?
in the constructor which is below:

```
public PersonInfo(Person person, List<PersonEvent> personEvents)
```

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would be mapped to several SQL queries returning plain tuples. What is the purpose?

Comment: write one @Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardly doubt it is possible. [JPQL subqueries](https://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/2.4.x/docbook/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries), which might help you outline `personEvents`, are allowed only in `where` and `having` clauses.

Instead, I'd suggest you to just embrace the query as-is and move the logic of gathering to your DAO tier. This link might be helpful: https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito. Declare a method `List<PersonEvent> findEventsForPerson(List<Integer> ids)`, implement custom repository for it, doing all nesessary JPQL queries and combinations there. But beware of [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue) issue.

Also it may be convenient to use [entity graphs](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) in such custom implementation.

EDIT: After rereading the spec on fresh mind, I realized that I have mistaken saying that subqueries are allowed *only* in WHERE/HAVING clauses. It says that it *may* be used there, which doesn't exclude the opposite. Anyway, even if it is possible, such approach (extracting relation via subqueries) would most probably lead to N+1 issues, unless JPA implementors are smart enough to predict that (I wouldn't count on that anyway).

Comment: Hmmm just yesterday i did subqueries in the SELECT clause and it works. I dont see that subqueries are only allowed in WHERE and HAVING.

Comment: I just quoted from JPQL spec. And WHERE/HAVING clauses are parts of SELECT query so where is contradiction? Are we talking on one thing?

Comment: `SELECT new domain.MyDTO(e.id, (HERE_MY_SUBQUERY)) FROM MyEntity e`

Comment: Weird. And what kind of subquery is there? Can you provide full example?

Comment: SELECT new domain.MyDTO(e.id, (SELECT COUNT(ent.id) FROM MyEntity ent WHERE ent.gruop = e.group)) FROM MyEntity e

Comment: Well the result of subquery is scalar afterall, so it doesn't solve the originator's question. Have you tried it with a select returning a tuple set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160692/discussion-between-robert-niestroj-and-skapral).

Comment: There is no need to. It seems I realized my mistake. Corrected the answer.